# not able to store value in text file using fstream

Tags: c++

i am new to c++ programming i am not able to store in a text file.It is a very simple program. i was storing the values using the same method earlier i was getting results.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ofstream fout("one.txt",ios::in);

  int val1, rel1;
  char val2[20], rel2[20];

  cout<<" \n enter the integer value";
  cin>>val1;
  cout<<" \n enter the string value ";
  cin>>val2;

  fout.close();

  ifstream fin("one.txt");

  fin>>rel1;
  fin>>rel2;

  cout<<"the integer value .\n"<<rel1;
  cout<<"the string value .\n"<<rel2;

  fin.close();

  if (fout==NULL) {
    cout<<"the file is empty";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**input 
100
name**
 Absurd output is
**the integer value is 32760
the string value is  00Dv0**

Comment: Is this what your code looks like in your IDE/text editor?

Comment: You don't actually do anything with `fout` except close it.

Comment: yes @JosephMansfield exactly same

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev please elaborate

Comment: In that case, you should indent your code better! I'm going to do it for you so you should see how it's done.

Comment: 1) You can't compare an object to 0/NULL. 2) You also should use std::string instead of char[] for storing text. 3) You never write anything to the file.

Comment: @user3383404 actually it does compile, apologies. Still `fout` is not a pointer and should not be compared to `NULL`. This only works because of the not so good implementation of fstream

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of assumptions here that seem to need clarification.

- If you want to write to the file you need to use fout << rel1;
- You (usually) can't compare an object against NULL like you do in if(fout == NULL). This works in C# and Java because in those languages all objects are actually references, in C++ you specify when you want an object and when you want a reference.
- You specify that you want to use fout to read from the file and not write to it, "ios::in".

I was a bit bored waiting for some tests to finish so I wrote how I would've written that program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>

int main() {
  std::ofstream fout("one.txt",std::ios::out);

  int val1, rel1;
  std::string val2, rel2;

  std::cout <<"enter the integer value: ";
  std::cin >>val1;
  std::cout <<"enter the string value: ";
  std::cin >>val2;

  fout <<val1 <<" " <<val2;
  fout.close();

  std::ifstream fin("one.txt", std::ios::in);
  if(!fin.good()) {
    std::cout <<"Failed to open file\n";
    return 1;
  }

  fin >>rel1;
  fin >>rel2;

  std::cout <<"the integer value: " <<rel1 <<"\n";
  std::cout <<"the string value: " <<rel2 <<"\n";

  fin.close();

  return 0;
}
```